# How can I remove / filter array elements based on duplicate substrings in associative array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, filter

I want to remove similar title based values eg. if I have Rihanna - Work Ft. Some other words and Rihanna - Work I want to have only one of them. How can I remove duplicates still seach for Rihanna. see below json that contains similar titles:

**Means I dont want to have multiple versions of a songs in my array**
**SEE BELOW SAMPLE JSON TO BE FILTERED OUT AS SINGLE VERSION**

```js
    {
      "videos": [
        {
          "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
          "etag": "\"gMxXHe-zinKdE9lTnzKu8vjcmDI/134M9maQodDR9PapI2tdE24XHdU\"",
          "id": "UExwWEExSXFCZ2VaUXpYOFh2Y0U0R0RscEFpTjAzczNGNi5EQUE1NTFDRjcwMDg0NEMz",
          "snippet": {
            "publishedAt": "2016-07-03T16:45:08.000Z",
            "channelId": "UCOb0YwX9e9SFbctQaSXkKGQ",
            "title": "Rihanna - Work ft. Drake (Audio)",
           
          },
          "shuffle_id": 88
        },
        {
          "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
          "etag": "\"gMxXHe-zinKdE9lTnzKu8vjcmDI/Qeo1vUZh73p7gX3EFvVxRGbTxms\"",
          "id": "UExaOW5LbUs1dVVCcnN2Rld6ZDRWcFA0MHZ3NlZhLXZFeS5ENDU4Q0M4RDExNzM1Mjcy",
          "snippet": {
            "publishedAt": "2016-08-31T04:42:26.000Z",
            "channelId": "UC2mUsMtec7AOG9K-4ZlO7gA",
            "title": "Rihanna - Work (Explicit) ft. Drake",
            "description": "",
            "channelTitle": "Dickinson Kenneth",
            "playlistId": "PLZ9nKmK5uUBrsvFWzd4VpP40vw6Va-vEy",
            "position": 17,
          
          },
          "shuffle_id": 219
        }]
 }
```

Comment: As you see through different value of elements so they are different hence the two tracks are different for the program. Now you may need to implement a logic according to you which makes it similar and on that basis you can filter

Comment: That is what I am asking...THE LOGIC

Comment: You could define a hash function for song titles. The ideea is that for two different but similar song titles the hash function gives you the same result.

Comment: What could be that HASH function logic?

Comment: I'm writing it right now :)

Comment: What makes you say the two song in the the given track are same

Comment: cool I am waiting @Constantin GALBENU

Comment: client says this :P @M A SIDDIQUI

Answer (score 0):

So, you could define a hash function that returns the same hash for similar song titles; then, you could make songs list unique based on that hash value.

This is a potential hash function and some demo:

```
$hash1 = hashSongTitle('Rihanna - Work ft. Drake (Audio)');
$hash2 = hashSongTitle('Rihanna - Work (Explicit) ft. Drake');

echo $hash1 . "\n";
echo $hash2 . "\n";

$sameHash = ($hash1 === $hash2);

echo $sameHash ? 'are the same' : 'not not the same';

function hashSongTitle($title)
{
    //get rid of noise words
    $title = str_replace(array('(Explicit)', '(Audio)', '-'), '', $title);

    //collapse consecutive spaces
    $title = preg_replace('#\s{2,}#ims', ' ', $title);

    //get rid of possible white spaces in front or in the back of the string
    $title  = trim($title, "\r\n ");

    return $title;
}
```

This should echo:

```
Rihanna Work ft. Drake
Rihanna Work ft. Drake
are the same
```

You could see it live here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/201b95cdc80f587a0ee377155c5fb6a49475bc89

Then, you could store the song in an array indexed by that hash value, so they become unique.

```
foreach($songList as $song)
{
    $hash = hashSongTitle($song->title);
    $uniqueSongList[$hash] = $song;
}
```

Comment: Thank You... well tried.. but Rihanna - Work ft. Drake (Audio) and Rihanna - Work (Explicit) ft. Drake are not hardcoded one they are appearing on fly from API... so these could be any values

Comment: Yes and you must define all the noise words like Explict or Audio

Comment: But they can be any :'( I just want Rihanna to be there and Work as Track Name and no other track with Work

Answer (score 0):

You can detect similarity using [similar_text](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.similar-text.php) function and decide a threshold to tell that two titles (or more) are similar enough to remove one of them (the shortest ?).

If you need to have more accurate results, which means that you are not only interested in the number of common letters but also in their order, then you are looking for the longest common substring problem, [here is an implementation](http://www.christopherbloom.com/2011/02/24/find-the-longest-common-substring-using-php/). Here you have to establish a threshold compared to the ratio largestSubstringLength/OriginalStringLength.